# Unproductive complaining and arguing about others pedagogy

Tags: discussion, comment

Please see the following discussion in the comments of my answer [If $a > b$, is $a^2 > b^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/if-a-b-is-a-b/8360#8360)

I feel this style of slightly rude comments which contain much more subjective argumentation than mathematical are actually confusing to readers (like who posted the question) and that it is counterproductive in general to waste time trying to force people to teach in the same was you like to teach.

My opinion is we should try and keep that type of comment to a minimum, but what does the rest of the community feel? (I am expecting that my opinion is the minority and mostly curious about peoples justification for disagreement).

Comment: My comments were untactful and unclear in terms of what I meant to express, and I apologize to Moron and muad.  Now that all of the comments have been removed, I feel like adding clarification, but am inclined to leave the original post alone. muad's answer makes rigorous a claim in the currently accepted answer (the inequality holds if $a$ and $b$ are positive), and therefore it adds something as a complement to that answer.

Comment: However, the last sentence, "That is why we need $b$ to be positive," could be interpreted as a statement that positivity of $b$ is necessary for the inequality to hold, rather than just for your particular argument.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer - by the way, it was nothing you said which I was bothered by.

Answer (score -2):

Argumentative comments removed.

Please refrain from arguing with your fellow community members. Spirited discussion is fine, but being overtly argumentative or rude is not tolerated here.

Comment: I did not intend to be argumentative or rude, nor did I have a problem with the other comments.  I just had a minor disagreement with part of Moron's criticism.  As it stands, the comment of mine that was deleted was an answer to a question that remains.

Comment: From my perspective the only really "bad" part was when muad more or less accused Moron of holding a grudge.  This was completely off-topic, and at the time I merely ignored it, but in retrospect it is probably best that it is gone.

Comment: I am in favor of moderators doing what is necessary to keep the site running smoothly, but I am not entirely comfortable with the procedure in this case.  Aside from the exception just mentioned, none of the comments was blatantly offensive or off-topic, and in such cases I would prefer for deletions to at least be more transparent.  E.g., the comments could be copied here.

Comment: @jonas at the point when the comments devolve into arguments and rudeness, we typically delete everything from that point onward. I recommend refraining from participating at all in comment threads that have devolved to argument and rudeness, as there is a high probability everything "downstream" of the argument will be removed. It's like a cancer -- you have to remove some of the surrounding healthy tissue to ensure safety.